# Error when try to create Service Reference in VS2013 with fault elements from third party WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I am creating a WCF Client in VS 2013 using a supplied third party WSDL for a web service - most likely running on Java.

Running svcutil on the raw WSDL gives me an error similar to this:

```
Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: 
//wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='<ns>']/wsdl:portType[@name='xxxPort']       
XPath to Error Source: 
//wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='<ns>']/wsdl:binding[@name='xxxPortSoap11']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: 
//wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='<ns>']/wsdl:binding[@name='xxxPortSoap11']
XPath to Error Source: 
//wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='<ns>']/wsdl:service[@name='xxxPortService']/wsdl:port[@name='xxxPortSoap11']

Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated. ...
```

In order to get the Service Reference working (or svcutil running without errors) I have to comment out the fault definitions in the port and bindings. I can live with that (as I have made a `MessageInspector` to pull out errors from the various detail elements), but want to get it working properly.

Simplifying the WSDL to only show the elements that give me problems gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/data/common/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:sch0="http://www.example.com/data/common/" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/data/common/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>

    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:tns1="http://www.example.com/data/common/" 
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        targetNamespace="www.example.com/data/common/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:complexType xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="BusinessErrorType">
        <xsd:sequence xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xsd:element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             name="Error" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        name="BusinessErrorFault" type="tns1:BusinessErrorType" />

    </xsd:schema>

  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="BusinessErrorFault">
    <wsdl:part name="BusinessErrorFault" element="sch0:BusinessErrorFault" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="ViewMessagesPort">

    <wsdl:operation name="BusinessError">
      <wsdl:fault name="BusinessErrorFault" message="sch0:BusinessErrorFault" />
    </wsdl:operation>

  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="ViewMessagesPortSoap11" type="sch0:ViewMessagesPort">

    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="BusinessError">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <wsdl:fault name="BusinessErrorFault">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="BusinessErrorFault" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>

  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="ViewMessagesPortService">
    <wsdl:port name="ViewMessagesPortSoap11" binding="sch0:ViewMessagesPortSoap11">
      <soap:address location="https://www.example.com/ws/" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

I have looked at many SO questions and other places on the net including [Scott Hanselman's breaking the rules](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BreakingAllTheRulesWithWCF.aspx) with no joy.

Hopefully it is something blindingly obvious ... I gratefully await any answers from across the pond as I wend my way home in the UK.

UPDATE

Passing the above WSDL through https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/ gives an error on the binding:

```
Style: Unknown [Warn!]
Could not detect the 'use' for the operations of binding ViewMessagesPortSoap11
```

I'm still none the wiser.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement - "Removing everything but one error gives the following simplified wsdl which gives the same error:"? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I hacked the WSDL removing everything that worked, leaving only one example of the thing that made the svcutil fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WSDL you published above has an issue that there is no schema with targetNamespace of "http://www.example.com/data/common/" which is what expected by the sch0:BusinessErrorFault element. I assume this may be because you did not provide the full WSDL so I changed the targetNamespace of the schema to it. The next error if this this operation:

```
<wsdl:operation name="BusinessError">
      <wsdl:fault name="BusinessErrorFault" message="sch0:BusinessErrorFault" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

has no input or output but just fault, which does not make since.

I guess this might also be because you simplified the WSDL so please publish the full one if you get more errors.

Comment: I anonymised the wsdl - example.com was not the original uri ... checking both versions ... if you notice,the top wsdl element does define sch0 but I may have deleted too much from the original. Get back to you in a min

Comment: That is how the WSDL was supplied. There were normal calls with inputs and outputs, but I just cut down the file to only show the problematic items. As stated in question, if I comment out the operations above in binding and portType then `svcutil` works. How do I change the Error operations to work - or is this un-fixable Java non-statndards wsdl.

Comment: when I did "add service reference" in VS and looked in the warnings pane the errors were slightly more detailed than what you gave. What is the exact error now? Also did not fully understand your last comment - does the original WSDL bind sch0 to a namespace that there is no schema with it as target namespace? does it have an operation with just fault and no input or output?

Comment: I was given three WSDLs that have the same problem: they have normal operations, but also fault-only operations as in example above. Only way I could get them working was remove the fault operations (e.g. BusinessError above) which had no input and output elements. My question is: is that the correct action (hacking WSDL) or am I at fault with my understanding; Is it me or the WSDL that is wrong?

Comment: Do you need the faulty operations or are you ok with the end result (after removing the operations)? If you are happy the next question is if you expect this WSDL to change a lot which might force you to recreate the proxy and repeat the manual work. For most cases I would recommend to remove the operations from the WSDL like you did and never look back.

Comment: Also don't bother with the question if the WSDL is right or wrong. There are so many implementations for this standard which differ from each other that I stopped asking this question a long time ago. While I don't see the value in a fault-only operation, maybe it makes some sense in the context of that java app. Just make sure you are not required to interact with those operations,